# Firefox extension auto installation

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm creating a Firefox extension and I have a folder with files of the extension. Every time I want to test in I have to zip it, change the extension to .xpi, drag&drop it to Firefox window, wait for 3 seconds, click install button and restart the browser.

I've made a batch file that zips the folder and changes the extension, but is it possible to reinstall it completely with the script, without drag&drop routine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit (2017-06-25)**: As of Firefox 57, classic extensions (including Extension Auto-Installer mentioned below) will stop working. This means that your choices are now:

- Go to `about:debugging` and load your extension as a temporary add-on. This will allow reloading it with a single click, whenever you make changes - either to a package or to an unpacked directory, both are possible.
- Use the [web-ext command line tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext), it can install your extension as a temporary add-on from the command line. It can also watch extension files for changes and reload automatically.

---

*Original answer for reference, will only work up to Firefox 56.*

Actually, that's why I created [Extension Auto-Installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/autoinstaller/) a while ago. Install the extension in your test browser and add the following to your batch script:

```
wget --post-file=extension.xpi http://localhost:8888/
```

This will automatically install your extension in the browser and restart it if necessarily. If signing extensions is required, it will offer to install the extension as a temporary add-on, for the current browser session only.

As you seem to be using Windows, you will need [Wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) or a similar command line tool.

Comment: I had to go to `about:config` and change the value of `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false` before this solution could work. Another option was to sign the xpi using the [jpm sign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#jpm_sign) command.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but:
You don't necessarily have to do that.

1. Open up *Help* menu.
2. Select *Troubleshooting Information*
3. Find *Profile Folder* and click on *Show Folder* button next to it. This will open your Firefox profile folder.
4. In the *extensions* folder, create a new folder with your extension ID or name. (Like this: `{8956a28d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`)
5. Just edit your extension files, and restart the browser. Changes will take effect in no time!

**Note**: First time you run Firefox after this implicit installation, you'll be asked to allow this installation; just allow it.

**P.S.** It's a good idea to have the *Extension Developer* add-on; it'll make things easy (For instance, restarting Firefox with one click).

Comment: Restarting Firefox all the time gets pretty tiresome very soon if you are working on a restartless extension.

Comment: @WladimirPalant: Instead, you don't have to reinstall the component at all! I've used this method and it was pretty cool! (with *Extension Developer* it was even better)

Comment: Yes, you don't need to reinstall - but you still have to restart the browser, something that is normally unnecessary with a restartless extension. And you will be fighting various browser caches. And you will get pretty inconsistent results if you edit the files while the browser is still running. I used that approach myself but got pretty annoyed by the issues and created Extension Auto-Installer.