# Firefox Not Recognizing my XUL Extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm new to Firefox XUL Development and I'm following this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension

My app id is "sample@example.net"

I'm using a Mac and I create a file in

```
/Users/bennettl/Library/Application Support/Mozilla/Extensions/sample@example.net
```

In my file I placed the absolute path of my extension

```
 /Users/bennettl/Desktop/my-firefox-extension/
```

I restarted Firefox, but my extension isn't being displayed at all!!

Comment: Don't start from scratch. People make a bunch of templates pick one of those up and use it. Just understand that XPI is a zip file. But they renamed the zip extension to xpi, otherwise you can't install to Firefox. Search for template with tag [firefox-addon] on stackoverflow

Comment: Here just click this link and look in these topics: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[firefox-addon]%20template

Comment: So I would need to re-zip to xpi, reinstall, and restart Firefox  every time I modify my code?

Comment: Not if you do a bootstrap addon. Or if you do an addon-sdk addon. here is an example of addon sdk [Annotator](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/tree/master/examples/annotator) to use sdk you have to set up the sdk environment [SDK Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) For restartless addons you just need notepad or some text edito examples are in the link in the topics in link I gave you above.

Comment: I experimented with the Firefox Add On SDK and it was too limited in its functionality so I need to work with XUL now. So my question was do I need to re-zip to xpi, reinstall, and restart Firefox every time I modify my XUL code?

Comment: AGAIN: "Not if you do a bootstrap addon." AND AGAIN: Look in the link i gave you with search results on SO, there are many example files attached there. In XPI format so you can just drag and drop into firefox. Bootstrap means it is a RESTARTLESS addon you can modify things there and install, you don't directly modify XUL overlays, is done during runtime.

Comment: Goodness here dude. The first topic in the list gives a full xpi template: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224263/trigger-firefox-extensions-from-a-custom-button/22231759#22231759). Now download that, install it, see how it works, then start editing it by renaming the XPI to zip and then extracting to folder, then editing, then re-zipping, then re-naming to XPI, then re-installing. There are addons to help you with this process.

Comment: You can use [XPICompiler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpicompiler/) you give a folder with bootstrap source files, it compiles and installs it to firefox.

Comment: What is it that you exactly want to do? I'll create a template/demo addon for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox extension auto installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597537/firefox-extension-auto-installation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox extension testing and developing - I'm confused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959858/firefox-extension-testing-and-developing-im-confused)